# firebase: ruby authentication with database secret

Tags: ruby, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-api, firebase-authentication

Re-asking [same](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40700485/262852) question because:

```
 Database Secrets
warning
Database secrets are currently deprecated and use a legacy Firebase token generator. Update your source code with the Firebase Admin SDK.
```

when getting the "secret" -- by which I infer they mean secret key.

for reference:

```
thufir@dur:~/ruby/firebase$ 
thufir@dur:~/ruby/firebase$ ./quickstart.rb 
true
200
{"name"=>"-Kxf9rMd9p1F0cb2HTeM"}
thufir@dur:~/ruby/firebase$ 
thufir@dur:~/ruby/firebase$ cat quickstart.rb 
#!/usr/bin/env ruby


require 'rubygems'
require 'firebase'
require 'pp'
require_relative 'config'



config = Config.new

#firebase = Firebase::Client.new(config.database_url)
firebase = Firebase::Client.new(config.database_url,config.database_secret)


response = firebase.push("todos", { :name => 'Pick the milk', :priority => 1 })
pp response.success? # => true
pp response.code # => 200
pp response.body # => { 'name' => "-INOQPH-aV_psbk3ZXEX" }
response.raw_body # => '{"name":"-INOQPH-aV_psbk3ZXEX"}'


thufir@dur:~/ruby/firebase$
```

this approach is relatively stable?  I copied the information from the Google console GUI:

```
Add Firebase to your web app

Copy and paste the snippet below at the bottom of your HTML, before other script tags.
```

into the config file for reference.  (Probably should use yaml or similar; works for now.)

Comment: and your question is?

Comment: this is how others are authenticating with firebase?  if so, then ok.